# List View Search Result Item Click

Tags: android

My list view 1. item click code:(1. item: Ali, 2. item: Mehmet)

(Ali click start Ali activity)

`if(position==0){
 startActivity(new Intent("og.hangitelefonualsam.Ali"));
 overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animasyon, R.animator.animasyon2);
}`

Works fine. But search result
Mehmet, Zeynep, Ahmet

Search result 1. item click start Mehmet activity. :(

Answer (score 0):

The statement `position == 0` is always going to start the Ali activity no matter what's on that position. To difference between items you can read the selected item and then start the correct activity. Change your onItemClick method to this:

```
String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

if(selectedItem.equals("Ali")) {
    startActivity(new Intent("og.hangitelefonualsam.Ali"));
    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animasyon, R.animator.animasyon2);
} else if(selectedItem.equals("Mehmet")) {
    startActivity(new Intent("og.hangitelefonualsam.Mehmet"));
    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animasyon, R.animator.animasyon2);
} else if(selectedItem.equals("Zeynep")) {
    startActivity(new Intent("og.hangitelefonualsam.Zeynep"));
    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animasyon, R.animator.animasyon2);
} ...
```

etc.

That way you are alway getting the right item regardless it's position on the list view